# Recursive display of remote desktop screen

Tags: lubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access, amazon-ec2, tightvncserver

I tried to set up remote desktop to connect to an Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance. The steps are:

(1) `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lightdm lubuntu-desktop tightvncserver`

(2) create a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` containing:

```
#
# VNC Server configuration
#
# enabled = True if VNC connections should be allowed
# port = TCP/IP port to listen for connections on
#
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
port=5900
width=1000
height=1000
depth=24
```

(3) `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`.

(4) login the EC2 instance using `ssh -i MyKeypair.pem ubuntu@my.ip.address -L 5900:localhost:5900`

(5) connect using Remmina Remote Destop Client:
[image]

(6) After clicking the "Connect" button, I got this strange screen in which windows are stacked recursively. It's very like a man standing between two mirrows.

[image]

My settings are: A Windows machine A is connecting to a Windows machine B using Windows's remote desktop, on B a ubuntu VM C is running in VMware workstation. The VM C takes the steps described above to connect to EC2 instance using its Remmina.

Could someone please find out what's wrong with it, and how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your own pc, there is already a vnc server running. So the port forwarding fails, as port 5900 is already open.

Change the ssh command:

```
ssh -i MyKeypair.pem ubuntu@my.ip.address -L 5901:localhost:5900
```

Then connect to:

```
localhost:5901
```

But let me add something here: What you are doing is the wrong way. Why do you want to administrate a **server** using a **GUI**?
You do have ssh, that's faster and made for administration.

Comment: Cool! I overlooked this point. Now I changed to 5902 (5900 is occupied by vino and 5901 by Xvnc4) and everything works! As for your addition, I think there is no inherent right or wrong about administrating a remote machine using command line or GUI. It's just a personal preference or style. In addition, ssh is not on the opposite side of GUI; GUI can run on ssh, as is the settings in my question. Third, there is no doubt that GUI is easier to use than command line, especially for those who are not professional system administrators. (more to continue ...)

Comment: Last, but more important, remote machine is not necessarily always the traditional server like database or web-server that a command line is enough to administrate. Remote machine is also needed when more computing power is demanded than what a local machine can afford. This situation is more clear if the task must be accomplished in an efficiently interactive way. For example, in scientific computing using Matlab or graphics rendering, we sometimes need to change the parameters and see what the result looks like in a figure, or is the new model parameter give us a more realistic simulation...

Comment: If we do these interactive job on local machine, we have to wait longer. But if we submit them to a powerful remote server, we can obtain more interactivity. Also, when the computing on the remote machines is completed, we can of course copy the results back to the local machine and view it in figures, but why not directly let the remote machine render the results, and we just press Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V to get what we ultimately want?

Comment: One may ask why not just spent $10000 to buy a powerful workstation. The key is price, and it's the key of success of cloud computing burgeoned nowadays.

Comment: I would recommend running Matlab with X over ssh.